# Unable to set enviornment variable for Oracle in Centos 5 32bit

Tags: centos5

Unable to set enviornment variable for Oracle in Centos 5 32bit. The values entered in the /.bash_profile file are not being changed.? what can be the Solution.?

Comment: Please show us at least commands that you have executed and how Oracle is started.

Comment: Basic command sqlplus " / as sysdba" it says.
Command not found.
More over When I do echo $ORACLE_PATH its empty or no value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add directory where 'sqlplus' is located to the PATH. The correct path to your profile is ~/.profile.

Comment: # Oracle Settings
TMP=/tmp; export TMP
TMPDIR=$TMP; export TMPDIR

ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.1.0/db_1; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=RAC1; export ORACLE_SID

PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH; export PATH
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/JRE:$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib; export CLASSPATH


This is how it looks like. But still the command is not working.
Moreover when I try to echo the echo $ORACLE_HOME. its shows no value. 
The ENV variable is not getting set.

Comment: Have you relooged into your shell after making changes to the file? Is this the file that holds your shell variables (default name for such file is ~/.profile)?

Comment: the file i have to use is /.bash_profile.
as I understand this helps me to use /.bashrc and /.profile files together to set variables.
Funnily, My collegue is using the same arguments and its working on his machine Centos 5 64 bit. SQLPLUS also works and echo aslo gives desired results.